# Want to remove drop shadow from my custom button?

Tags: c#, .net

I made a custom button using C#. But the drop shadow or something else is the main problem which is not removing form the button.

[How can I remove that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psUqq.jpg)

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ButtonZ
{
    public class ButtonZ : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        Color clr1, clr2;
        private Color color1 = Color.LightGreen;
        private Color color2 = Color.DarkBlue;
        private Color m_hovercolor1 = Color.Yellow;
        private Color m_hovercolor2 = Color.DarkOrange;
        private int color1Transparent = 150;
        private int color2Transparent = 150;
        private Color clickcolor1 = Color.DarkOrange;
        private Color clickcolor2 = Color.Red;
        private int angle = 90;
        private int textX = 100;
        private int textY = 25;
        private String text = "";

       public String DisplayText
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { text = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color StartColor
        {
            get { return color1; }
            set { color1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color EndColor
        {
            get { return color2; }
            set { color2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color MouseHoverColor1
        {
            get { return m_hovercolor1; }
            set { m_hovercolor1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color MouseHoverColor2
        {
            get { return m_hovercolor2; }
            set { m_hovercolor2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color MouseClickColor1
        {
            get { return clickcolor1; }
            set { clickcolor1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color MouseClickColor2
        {
            get { return clickcolor2; }
            set { clickcolor2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int Transparent1
        {
            get { return color1Transparent; }
            set
            {
                color1Transparent = value;
                if (color1Transparent > 255)
                {
                    color1Transparent = 255;
                    Invalidate();
                }
                else
                    Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int Transparent2
        {
            get { return color2Transparent; }
            set
            {
                color2Transparent = value;
                if (color2Transparent > 255)
                {
                    color2Transparent = 255;
                    Invalidate();
                }
                else
                    Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int GradientAngle
        {
            get { return angle; }
            set { angle = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int TextLocation_X
        {
            get { return textX; }
            set { textX = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public int TextLocation_Y
        {
            get { return textY; }
            set { textY = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public ButtonZ ()
        {
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);
            this.ForeColor = Color.White;
            this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;

        }
        //method mouse enter
        protected override void OnMouseEnter (EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            clr1 = color1;
            clr2 = color2;
            color1 = m_hovercolor1;
            color2 = m_hovercolor2;
        }
        //method mouse leave
        protected override void OnMouseLeave (EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            color1 = clr1;
            color2 = clr2;
        }
        //method mouse click
        protected override void OnMouseClick (MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Clicks == 1)
            {
                base.OnMouseClick(e);
                color1 = clickcolor1;
                color2 = clickcolor2;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            text = this.Text;
            if (textX == 100 && textY == 25)
            {
                textX = ((this.Width) / 3) + 10;
                textY = (this.Height / 2) - 1;
            }
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(color1Transparent, color1);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(color2Transparent, color2);
            //drawing string & filling gradient rectangle 
            Brush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, c1, c2, angle);
            Point p = new Point(textX, textY);
            SolidBrush frcolor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
            Border3DStyle borderStyle = Border3DStyle.SunkenInner;
            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(b , ClientRectangle);
            pe.Graphics.DrawString(this.text, this.Font, frcolor, p);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(pe.Graphics, ClientRectangle, borderStyle);
            b.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Border3DStyle borderStyle = Border3DStyle.SunkenInner;`

`ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(pe.Graphics, ClientRectangle, borderStyle);`?

Comment: It ceratinly doensn't look like a drop shadow, so edit the title! - I would try to see if the Text is drawn twice, once by the base and once by your code. Add a character to what you draw to test it. If it is the problem, replace the Text by a property of your own!

Comment: I have mention that it is looking like drop shadow, if i change the text or remove, back text also remove.